# Custom layouts, Sublime text 2

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

I've been working with a 2 column system so far but feel I'm needing a third and that 3 spread across the screen doesn't give much of a view without adjusting the width every time.

It's there a way to get the grid layout but have the bottom half of the screen one file.
I know it's a long shot but wondering if anyone knows of anything
[image: Current system]

Found that you can edit for custom layouts in Packages/default/Main.sublime-menu
Having problems saving though `error in trying to parse file: expected value in ~/library/application support/sublime text 2/packages/default/Main.sublime-menu:407:21`

**Edited: for better layout**

Found something that is similar, been trying to mod it but don't understand how the cells work

This one is similar

```
"args":
{
    "cols": [0.0, 0.5, 1.0],
    "rows": [0.0, 0.5, 1.0],
    "cells": [
        [0, 0, 1, 2], // (0.0, 0.0) -> (0.5, 1.0)
        [1, 0, 2, 1], // (0.5, 0.0) -> (1.0, 0.5)
        [1, 1, 2, 2]  // (0.5, 0.5) -> (1.0, 1.0)
    ]
}
```

which gives

[image: Code]

Comment: Have you tried asking in the Sublime Text forums?

Comment: Check out [Origami](https://github.com/SublimeText/Origami), a plugin for pane-management in sublime text

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Assuming these are just coordinates with 0,0 at the upper left, something like this should work:

```
[0, 0, 1, 1],
[1, 0, 2, 1],
[0, 1, 2, 2]
```

**Edit**: Just tested, and it does.

Create the file `Main.sublime-menu` in your Packages > User folder (best to leave the default menu alone) and put the following code in it:

```
[{
    "id": "view",
    "children": [{
        "id": "layout",
        "children": [{
             "command": "set_layout",
             "caption" : "Custom: 3 Pane",
             "mnemonic": "C",
             "args": {
                "cols": [0.0, 0.5, 1.0],
                "rows": [0.0, 0.5, 1.0],
                "cells": [
                    [0, 0, 1, 1],
                    [1, 0, 2, 1],
                    [0, 1, 2, 2]
                ]
            }
        }]
    }]
}]
```

You will see `Custom: 3 Pane` in your layout options. No need to restart Sublime Text.

For anyone interested, [here is a gist](https://gist.github.com/4073661) containing this layout as well as a flipped version.

Comment: Perfect :D thanks so much, can you explain how the co-ordinates work for the cells?

Comment: In this case, the upper left corner of the entire window is coordinate 0,0 and the bottom right is 2,2. For each cell, the first coordinate (`[0, 0` for the first one) is the upper left corner, and the second (`1, 1]`) is the lower right corner. It's kind of hard to explain in text, but you can Google "coordinate graph" for clarification.

Comment: This is great - thanks, @Sara. One correction, when creating it in your Packages > User folder, the file should be named `Main.sublime-menu` instead of `Main-sublime.menu`

Comment: Thanks, that was a typo on my part.

Answer (score 3):

This was very helpful for visualizing what points the coordinates are referring to: http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=7284&start=0&hilit=set+layout