# More than four panels Sublime Text?

Tags: sublimetext2, text-editor, sublimetext, sublimetext3

does any know any packages for Sublime Text that will allow more than 4 panels at once? You can change between different layouts "Grid: 4" or "Columns: 4" but I'm looking for something along the lines of an 8 panel grid or possibly another combination with 6-8 panels at once.

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13149800/custom-layouts-sublime-text-2 already? It has some great tips on creating a custom layout and the plugin [Origami](https://github.com/SublimeText/Origami) which might also help.

Comment: No I have not. I did some searching with out any luck but this looks great, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [Origami](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Origami) plugin, available through [Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net) or on [GitHub}(https://github.com/SublimeText/Origami). It basically allows you to split your window however you want - you can create new panes, delete panes, move and clone views from pane to pane - you don't need to manually edit `.sublime-keymap` files. Somebody [mentioned it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17620503/1426065) a month or two back, and I really like it. If you look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17621691/1426065) to that question, it details how to save an Origami layout with a custom key binding.

---

**EDIT**: I just noticed somebody beat me to the recommendation in the comments. It's still a good answer, though...

Answer (score 4):

For more details on creating a new menu item, see [Custom layouts, Sublime text 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13149800/custom-layouts-sublime-text-2).

I prefer to just hook up a keyboard shortcut to change the layout by editing the `Preferences` → `Key Bindings - User` file. Here is a 6 panel layout keyboard shortcut, which is working for me in Sublime Text 3.

```
[
    {
        "keys": ["alt+shift+6"],
        "command": "set_layout",
        "args":
        {
            "cols": [0.0, 0.25, 0.5, 1.0],
            "rows": [0.0, 0.5, 1.0],
            "cells":
            [
                [0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 2, 1], [2, 0, 3, 1],
                [0, 1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 2, 2], [2, 1, 3, 2]
            ]
        }
    }
]
```